# Protect remote resources when served with nodejs

Tags: node.js

This is more of an architecture question involving nodejs as implementation.

I have on a folder not exposed by the webserver files that I want to offer to the user.

The way nodejs should expose the resource to the end user is via a one shot link, that once is consumed is no longer available.
The user through the entire experience should never know the real location of the file.

I'm sure this is a common architecture pattern, but I have never implemented something similar.
Looking at scalability, the resource shouldn't be copy either on HD or RAM, and if possible the solution should not relay on a DB token tracking system.

I don't necessary need a code implementation, but a detail explanation on how I should implement it

Thank you so much

Comment: Some kind of token you have to save.

Comment: Ok, my users have all Json Web token. Can we maybe do something encoded with that?  In the worst case, I can use the DB, just wanted to keep it light

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Give user a cookie
- Create a temporary association (in db) between cookie and a generated ID for the user (or the hash of it, if you want to be fancy)
- Give user the ID

When user requests resource by ID:

- Test to see if the ID (or its hash, if you want to be fancy) is in the DB
- If it is, give the user the resource and destroy the association between the user and the resource ID

There's a db token tracking system. Hey, that's the only way.

Comment: Re Ram/HD copy, I mean on the server side. Let's pretend i have all the resources in partition D:/  and the webserver is running on a subfolder of E:/.  I would prefer not to copy the file in the webserver folder, or need to use the ram as solution (ie: using a web streaming protocol)

Comment: Oh, then where do you want it stored?

Comment: Was wondering if there can be an alias to the right destination that can hide the real destination to the end user.

Comment: @Snick You can just route the http request to the file. The file path and http request path don't need to match.

Answer (score 4):

One way to avoid depending on a DB, would be to maybe create a symbolic link in the filesystem (based on the token), that would be removed after a request for it. Would not work satisfactory on windows though.

Example (psuedo):

- Create token (guid, or similar)
- symlink guid -> actual file
- once request is completed, remove symlink

However, I don't think there is a reliable way of knowing if the file was successfully downloaded, so you better prepare for that. Some sort of pingback when the file was completely downloaded is probably the most reliable way that I can think of right now.

For scalability, make sure that the symlink is on a shared file system. Clustered node.js instances on the same server, will be fine though.

If this needs to be restricted to an authenticated user, you could combine the guid with your auth token, and prepend/append it before looking for a file.

Comment: how can I send back from a nodejs request, a path to a file that is outside the webserver ?   Example:  /datastore is the datastore, /webserver the webserver.  How can i resolve the request localhost/1.file    to the physical file /datastore/1.file ?

Comment: Depends on if you want to serve it statically or not. You can either just create the symlink in your /webserver folder, or route the request through a filereader and pipe it. If you want to add an extra auth-check you will have to route it yourself, something like: /download/guid.file -> check that {usertoken}-{guid}.file exists as symlink (in designated folder), then read and pipe {usertoken}-{guid}.file to output stream. Once finished, delete symlink.

Comment: I quickly implemented a pipe solution. Unfortunately I'm not 100% sure what's going on under the hood when calling pipe. Is it a memory trick? is just a reference? is it a scalable solution when pointing at a 100mb file ?

Comment: @Snick It is my understanding that it should be fine. It is basically just a forward between two streams, and it will read at the maximum rate allowed for the receiving stream. Unless the receiving stream has an infinite buffer, you shouldn't waste more than the intermediate buffer.